# wp7 hyperlinks not visible

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, hyperlink

RTM version of the developer tools.

I am building an app. In parts of the app I have some text provided by a web service, I take this text and process it to make the URLs in the text act as hyperlinks.

The container for this is a wrap panel.

```
<wrap:WrapPanel x:Name="PostMessage2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

Then in the constructor of the page I have this simple code.

```
PostMessage2.Children.Add(new HyperlinkButton()
    {
         Content = new TextBlock()
         {
             Text = "test url",
             Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)
         },
         NavigateUri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/")
    });
```

(I know this code is will not open an IE session and navigate to the Url)

Now when I run this program, I will not see anything visible on the screen, but if I tap the screen where the start of the url should be, then it will try to navigate to the url (which causes an exception as the navigation isn't handled correctly).

If I add a Textblock before and after the URL the test in those blocks is visible, and they will be separated by approximately 3 spaces, which if you tap the middle of this it will try to navigate to the url.

So my question is why are the hyper-links not visible but they are active as you can tap them, am I missing some obvious property or setting?

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to set the Content of the HyperlinkButton to be a TextBlock. It's expecting a string and you can set the Foreground color on the HLB:

```
PostMessage2.Children.Add(new HyperlinkButton()
    {
         Content = "test url",
         Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White),
         NavigateUri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/")
    });
```

Comment: Thats brilliant thanks, i have spent hours looking at this code, and i never thought to just use a string.